# how can i sort in alphabetic mode my spinners?

Tags: android, eclipse, spinner, sorting, alphabetical

i've create this code to create one list in my spinner. now i want the list in alphabetical mode (for example xxx, yyy, aaa must be aaa, xxx, yyy)..how can i do?

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {


      private Spinner spinner;
      private EditText Text;
      private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
      private Button addButton;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        List<String> planets = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.clienti_arrays)));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planets);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        Collections.sort(planets);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_new);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
            addNewSpinnerItem();
          }
        });
      }

      protected void addNewSpinnerItem()
      {
        String textHolder = "" + Text.getText().toString();
        adapter.add(textHolder);

      }
    }
```

help me please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked docs? There is [sort method in ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29).

You just need to implement your own Comparator. I guess it's just:

`int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
}`

:)

Comment: i've implements Comparator<String> and at the end of the code i've insert     public int compare(String s1, String s2) { return s1.compareTo(s2); }..don't function!why?

Comment: sorry..i've solved but it sort firt capital letters and after lowercase letters..why? For example first XXX, YYY, ZZZ and after aaa, bbb, ccc

Comment: Because that's the way Java compares String objects. If you want to modify it, you should change the compare function: int compare(String s1, String s2) { return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase()); }

Answer (score 0):

```
 addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        addNewSpinnerItem();
        Collections.sort(adapter);
      }
 });
```

Maybe?